# Uninstall Sublime Text 3 downloaded and installed as a .deb from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, sublime-text, software-uninstall

I downloaded the 64-bit `.deb` installer of Sublime Text 3 for Ubuntu
and then I installed it using the setup from the software installer.

It was the paid version, so it is asking for the license key which I don't have. So I tried uninstalling Sublime Text but I am unable to do so.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Which repository did you install it from? Did you run 'sudo apt-get remove sublime-text' then 'sudo apt-get remove sublime-test-installer' and if so, what was the result? Please click on the edit link in grey at above left and add your findings to the original post.

Comment: Yeah, done . I deleted the subl files from the usr/bin . Then i again went to a website to download the sublime text (unregistered) ,it gave the steps for terminal, i followed the same ,and done.

Answer (score 4):

First you should check the packege-name with

```
dpkg -l | grep sublime
```

then you can remove it. It should be called something like sublime-text-installer.

```
dpkg -r sublime-text-installer
```

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall the editor with the following command in a terminal:

`sudo apt purge sublime-text`

If you are being asked for a licence key then you downloaded a development build which is intended for use by licensed users only. A trial version of the application is available from http://www.sublimetext.com/3.

You will not be asked to input a licence key when starting Sublime Text provided it is **not** a development build.